# increase eclipse IDE font size

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am using Eclipse

```
Spring Tool Suite 

Version: 3.9.4.RELEASE
Build Id: 201804120921
Platform: Eclipse Oxygen.3a (4.7.3a)
```

I would like to increase the font size of the IDE, not just the font of the editor. Is there any way I can do that? I haven't been able to find a solution for this yet.

Answer (score 4):

you can try the combination of Ctrl+Shift+'+'. That will enlarge the fonts of the text areas. Ctrl+Shift+'-' will reduce the fonts size, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

You can define most of the font sizes in Eclipse/STS via the preferences. In addition to that some font sizes are controlled by the operating system (for example the font that is used for tree views on macOS). Changing those font sizes typically require some OS-specific settings, e.g.: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24621/how-to-increase-font-size-of-eclipse-globally

Answer (score 0):

From the URL @MartinLippert provided I found this solutions https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/309209/293897 that changed the fonts in the entire UI except for menus.